# Difficulty understanding JSON escape characters

Tags: python, json, escaping, special-characters

I'm quite new to programming and recently have dived into the topic of **JSON Escape and special characters in Python**. I understand how to escape double quotation marks. For example:

**import json**

**data = json.loads('{"Test": "In \\"quotation\\" marks"}')**

**print(data)**

returns(as a "dict"): **{'Test': 'In "quotation" marks'}**

But I can't wrap my head around how the other special characters would be used like: **\b, \n, \, \f etc...**

Could someone please show me some examples of code where and how those other special escape characters would be used in, say for example, a json.loads functions like above. I'd be very grateful. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "how the other special characters would be used?" If you're wondering how to escape the characters, it would just be the same as with the quotation marks (e.g. `\\/b`). If you're wondering WHY a character like that would be used, it could be for any multitude of reasons. For example, a file path value such as `/b/Usr/etc`

Comment: Hi @lawgik. I just realized I wrote the escape characters incorrectly. I edited them, should be correct now. As for what I mean: There's something I'm missing in understanding what these escape characters actually do. For instance, I understand that \" allows us to use quotation marks inside a string without breaking the code(hence, escape). Now let's take \b, backspace, for example. If I write data = json.loads('{"Test": "In \b "quotation" marks"}'), for example, it causes an error. Obviously Im missing something here in terms of what this particular escape character is doing and how I use it

Answer (score 0):

JSON strings must be double quoted; as such, you need to escape a double quote in order to include it in a JSON string.

However, you *also* need to escape the backslash in the Python string literal in order to get a literal backslash in the JSON value. You can do that as you show in your question:

```
'{"Test": "In \\"quotation\\" marks"}'
```

or by using a raw string literal

```
r'{"Test": "In \"quotation\" marks"}'
```

Part of the confusion comes from the fact that JSON string values and Python string literals can look identical. For example, a JSON string that consists of a linefeed would look like

```
"\n"
```

and a Python string literal defining a string that consists of a linefeed would *also* look like

```
"\n"
```

A Python string literal defining a string that contains a JSON string consisting of a line feed would then be either

```
'"\\n"'
```

or

```
r'"\n"'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my question was relating specifically to how we would use, in your particular example, \n. For example, json.loads('{"Test": "In quotation marks"} \\n '), does this even make sense? \n is supposed to escape a new line but what does that actually mean? How would it look in a specific example of code? This is what I'm struggling with. Thanks

Comment: It means the string encoded as JSON includes a newline. Consider `json.dumps('\n')`, which returns `'"\\n"'`. JSON doesn't care about the content of the string; whether it makes sense for the string to contain a newline is up to whoever created the value in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I figured it out. My problem was that when I was doing

**data = json.loads('{"Test": "In quotation \\n marks"}')**

**print(data)**

it would return: **{'Test': 'In quotation \n marks '}** and I was trying to understand why it shows \n instead of an actual new line

I realized the escapes only show up when you look for value of a given key. So for example,

**print(data["Test"])** returned

**In quotation**

**marks**

same thing for **data = json.loads('{"Test": "In "quotation" \\bmarks"}')**

returns = **In quotationmarks**